# density curve in bar chat in

Tags: r, curve

```
H <- c(1,2,4,1,0,0,3,1,3,3, 6,238,0,58,17,64,38,3,10,8, 10,11,13,7,25,11,12,13,28,44)
M <- c("29/02","01/03","02/03","03/03","04/03","05/03","06/03","07/03","08/03", 
       "09/03","10/03","11/03","12/03","13/03","14/03","15/03","16/03", 
       "17/03","18/03","19/03","20/03","21/03","22/03","23/03","24/03", 
       "25/03","26/03","27/03","28/03","29/03")
```

"H "are the values of y axis and  "M" is the x axis,
can you help me please with the code because I don't know how to make this bar chart and density curve as in the picture below

[image]

Comment: That's probably not a barchart but a histogram!

Comment: in every date i put the case recorded ,

Comment: Hi @Starter, welcome to SO. I noticed you posted a very similar question with the same image. You can use some of the good answers provided in the other question to do what you need here

Comment: Otherwise can you improve the question by being more specific? Because what you have now is a barplot, if you want to create a density you need to apply the density function back onto the raw data. I might be wrong, but I have a feeling this is going around in circles and your questions are sending SO users into the same one as well